# How to solve variable not in context error in C#?

Tags: c#, class, var

I want that the sound plays if I press the key and stop if I release the key.

But I don't know how I could stop the sound in the `KeyUp` statement, because it says `p46` isn't in the context. I read that this isn't possible with variables, but is it true? Which method can I use here to make it work?

I also want it to play 2 sounds at the same time.

```
void Test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        var p46 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        p46.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Sonstiges\LaunchBoard\LaunchBoard\bin\Debug\Sounds\Song1Audio41.wav"));
        p46.Volume = TrackWave.Value / 10.00;
        p46.Play();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        button19.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}

void Test_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        button19.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        button19.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really in another class, or another method of the same class? If the latter, use a member variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doctorlove (comment above) is right. You need to use the `MediaPlayer` from two difference methods, not two classes. So just move it to the class-scope. That is what is called a (private) ***field***.

It looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Xx
{
  class Yy
  {
    MediaPlayer p46 = new MediaPlayer(); // field (class-level variable), 'var' not allowed

    void Test_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
      {
        // can see p46 here:
        p46.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\Sonstiges\LaunchBoard\LaunchBoard\bin\Debug\Sounds\Song1Audio41.wav"));
        p46.Volume = TrackWave.Value / 10.00;
        p46.Play();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        button19.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
    }

    void Test_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      // can see p46 here:
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed!